# How can i use http 1.1 pipelining from a desktop Java application (J2SE)?

Tags: http, request, java, pipelining

I'm making a simple Java app that makes 40 requests (each request has a unique URL) to a define server ... there is a simple way to make that 40 request with HTTP 1.1? I need to use only 1 tcp connection...

Thanks in advance

Diego

Answer (score 0):

[Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) supports HTTP 1.1 with [persistent connections](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e474).

Comment: Ok... seems to be the answer to my prays :) but... it seems to be a little bit complicate for the intended purposes of my app...  I'm developing just a java example only to compare (times) to a already C# console app..